# CE 1.9.1 - Automatically adjust product data from XML import

Tags: import, xml, ce-1.9.1.0, cron, products-management

I have a site already configured on Magento CE 1.9.1.0 ... This site needs to integrate with a Point-of-Sale system for the bricks-and-mortar store. I have spoken to the developers of the Point-of-Sale system, and they have mentioned that whenever a sale is made in store or inventory is adjusted, the system will create an XML file for the order and upload it into a designated folder on the web server.

My challenge now is processing that XML file. I've been looking for an extension to assist with this, but thus far no luck finding any. I know that the solution will involve cron having to run every X number of minutes to check the folder to see if there are any files to process.

Please advise me on what my options are? Really in the dark on this one. Thanks!

Comment: You can try https://github.com/ho-nl/Ho_Import which should provide the requested features. Personally, I'd take https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_FastSimpleImport and wrap a custom module around it which looks for files and processes them, transforming them to the array format used there.

Comment: Thank you Andreas! Ill have a look at t he AvS code. My php skills arent that grand to be honest but I'll give it a go

Comment: Actually, the H&O module says that it uses the AvS module code as well. So maybe i should try first with that?